# javascript: empty array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, api

I have the following loop which calls an api and pushes data to an array, the issue is that the API is returning empty values for certain attributes i.e   `"primaryTag": null` and is breaking my code, how can I handle it to place a static value if any of the values are null?

```
for (var a in audience) {
        
      var aId = audience[a];
      var url = base+'?'+query+'&AudienceId='+aId
      var req = new HttpClientRequest(url);
      req.header["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
      req.method = "GET"
      req.execute();
      var resp = req.response;  
       
      if( resp.code != 200 )
      throw "HTTP request failed with " + resp.message
         
      var posts = JSON.parse(resp.body)
      logInfo(resp.code+' '+url);

      
        for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
          articlesList_json.push({
                "title":posts[i].title, 
                "pubDate":posts[i].publishedDate, 
                "link":posts[i].url, 
                "imageURL":posts[i].imageUrl, 
                "description": posts[i].description,
                "category": posts[i].category.name,
                "audience": posts[i].audience.name+'-'+posts[i].audience.id,
                "tag": posts[i].primaryTag.name,
                "episerverId":posts[i].episerverId,
            });
        } 
      
}//for loop end
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is `HttpClientRequest` part of a library? Where is that coming from? When I google it, I get Adobe links. Is this part of an Adobe framework?

Comment: Thanks zero, indeed is a adobe campaign function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```
"tag": posts[i].primaryTag?.name ?? "N/A"
```

Alternatively use a ternary:

```
"tag": posts[i].primaryTag ? posts[i].primaryTag.name : "N/A"
```

Comment: @DavidGarcia I have added a proper ternary test too

Answer (score 1):

Values like null, undefined, empty Strings, 0 and NaN evaluated as false in Javascript.

You can check if the value is not null with an if condition

```
if(value) {
// value is not null
// do something with the value
}
```

In your example u can use a ternary expression to check this in place

```
        for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
          articlesList_json.push({
                // check if value is not falsy and provide a default when it is
                "title":posts[i].title ? posts[i].title : "no value",
                // ...
            });
        }
```

check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator for more information

Comment: Thanks both solutions work.